# InfluxDB time is behind by 15 minutes

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am using InfluxDB with Grafana to make some good visualizations. It was working fine for sometime, but recently I have seen the time of influx gone behind by 15 minutes. I can confirm this  by running below command in terminal

```
SHOW DIAGNOSTICS
```

It returns me the time 15 minutes behind the actual UTC.

```
name: system
PID  currentTime                    started                        uptime
---  -----------                    -------                        ------
6076 2019-12-26T04:22:12.003647626Z 2019-12-16T09:51:45.227606894Z 234h30m26.776040732s
```

UTC time at the moment this question asked was :

```
4:37 am
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards

Comment: Is your OS time NTP synchronized?

Comment: No it is not NTP synchronized!

Comment: So synchronize your time. Configure NTP properly in your OS.

Comment: I am not sure if that would matter as my system current time is correct and it is not UTC but IST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured what the problem was. In my Red hat linux machine, where the grafana and Influx installed , system time zone (Influx takes time data from system time) was set as Nepal which is `(GMT+5:45)` where as Grafana time zone(Which is set to take the local browser time data) was set as India which is `(GMT+5:30)`. That is why the exact 15 minutes difference in time series data. I hope someone will be beneficial with this information.